# Как улучшить классы?

Tags: c++

Как можно улучшить эти два класса? По заверению проверяющего тут что-то нехорошо, никак не возьму в толк, о чем он. До этого работал на C# и java...

```
Class T
{
    int _i;
    public:
    T(int i){_i=i};
    virtual void f();
    ~T();
}

Class T1: public T
{
    public:
    T1();
    virtual void f();
    ~T1();
}
```

Comment: >По заверению проверяющего тут что-то не хорошо

проверающий так и сказал "тут что-то нехорошо"?

Comment: Да, говорит эти два класса можно улучшить.

Comment: Имена же...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

На самом деле проблем у вас тут больше чем кода. Начнем с того, что код просто не компилируется - вместо **class** вы пишете **Class**, в конце каждого класса отсутствует  точка с запятой, то же самое - в конструкторе после инструкции **_i=i**. Кроме того, не хватает определений для виртуальных функций (впрочем, можно предположить, что они просто вами не приведены)

Но это все мелочи. Самое главное, что скорее всего подразумевал ваш проверяющий - это тот замечательный факт, что в ваших классах есть виртуальные функции, но нет виртуальных деструкторов, что, кк известно, способно привести к утечке памяти. 
Проблема старая и давно известная, вот ее [пример](http://ideone.com/j78F0J). Как можно видеть, в этом случае не вызывается деструктор класса **T1*? что способно привести к утечке памяти. Как с этим бороться? Довольно просто - объявить виртуальные деструкторы. [Пример](http://ideone.com/j78F0J)/ Здесь, как можно видеть, деструкторы вызываются корректно.

Эта проблема возникает из-за того, что раз деструктор не является виртуальным, то его вызов осуществляется с помощью так называемого раннего связывания - исходя из указателя на базовый класс. Объявление деструктора (и функции вообще) виртуальным заставляет компилятор осуществлять так называемое позднее связывание и обращаться к деструктору фактического типа (не базового)

Comment: Да, деструкторы я не трогал никогда, в C# об этом голова не болит. Понял, в первую очередь смотрю в раздел виртуальных функций и деструкторов. А что есть такое ~T(); ? Я в C++ встречал ~ только в качестве побитового отрицания...

Comment: А, понял. Про тильду я смогу узнать в том же разделе деструкторов. Благодарю всех за ответы!

Comment: @Saint если вы язали C#, то подобный синтаксис могли видеть и там. Только в случае с шарпом это уже не деструкторы, а финализаторы. Понятия схожие/, но не идентичные

Answer (score 3):

Называть переменную класса `_i` - как-то грубо. В целом, переменные `i`,`j` и `k` используются для переменных цикла, и читающий код это ожидает.

Переменная `_i` приватная (да, для классов по умолчанию переменные без явного указания доступа приватные, а для структур - публичные).

Дальше. У вас есть виртуальный метод и есть наследование. А это говорит о том, что нужно делать виртуальный деструктор. Думаю, что это один с основных моментов.

Используется явная инициализация в конструкторе. Хотя можно это сделать красивее. Я бы писал так:

```
T(int i): _i(i) {};
```

И под самый конец. Многие считают, что в начале должны идти публичное, а все приватное - в конец.

Answer (score 0):

Ну например: переменная _i вроде должна быть приватной. Но у нее нет указателя доступа. Значит, она private. Я всегда стараюсь делать так:

```
class game{
  public:
    методы
  private:
    переменные и тп.
};
```

То есть, из соображения инкапсуляции, доступ к переменным должен быть ТОЛЬКО через методы. А сами переменные должны быть приватными.

Кстати, классы в c++ после фигурных скобок закрываются точкой с запятой.

Comment: Методы/переменные класса в C++ приватные по дефолту.